# Firebase how to dynamically search for a push key under a user's data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
    "foo":{
        "uid":{ // user's uid
            "push_key_1":{
               "bar":"baz"
            },
            "push_key_2":{
               "bar":"baz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given the code model above, how do I dynamically search for the `push_key_1` or `push_key_2` in a query?

I've tried to do :

```
var searKey = 'push_key_1';

db.ref('foo').orderByKey().equalTo(searKey).once('value')
    .then(function(snap){
        // snap.val() returns null.
    }).catch();
```

But the `snap.val()` is `null`. Turns out `orderByKey()` is for sorting purposes only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler than what you're trying. When you know the key of the node you want to load, you don't need a query at all:

```
db.ref('foo').child(searKey).once('value'....
```

Comment: but the child of `foo` is the `uid` right? Will it bypass its parent?

Comment: This will return `null` :/

Comment: Sure Frank no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible unless you restructure the database. My approach is to add another node to store the push keys.

```
"users_push_keys": {
    "push_key_1": "uid_1",
    "push_key_2": "uid_1"
}
```

With this, you can get the uid by retrieving the data from this node.
Hope this helps :)